# Term to express a range of fluctuation

Tags: word-choice, terminology, technical

I am trying to make a term for a function equipped on an image sensor.
The term is to express "the upper limit of fluctuation allowance in image size which is specified in %"

The value of percentage does not express the ratio of the enlarged image size compared to the original image size, so for example, 150% does not mean that the sensor will only detect a 150% bigger image to the original image.

Instead, it is to express the range of percentage of size fluctuation for sensor to accept to detect the shape (image) which makes 150% to mean that the sensor will detect an upscaled original image in all upscaling rate from 101% to 150%, such as a 102%, 117%, or 142% bigger image to the original image.

Does any of the followings describe the concept well?
If not, what is the problem?

> - Maximum size fluctuation allowance percentage
> - Maximum size volatility allowance percentage

Or,

> - Size fluctuation allowance percentage upper limit
> - Size volatility allowance percentage upper limit

Or, maybe "percentage" better be "rate"? 
Also, all of the candidates seem redundant. Any term to combine some words?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about "Image *rescaling detection cap*"?

Comment: Maximum Scaling Factor?

Comment: @Dan, does "cap" stand for "upper limit"? Is it used commonly? If so, it is a good term to know for me.

Comment: @Marv, when I look up "scale factor" on Wikipedia, it says it is "coefficient". Does it also imply "range"? Because the substance of the concept of what I am trying to explain is "limit of range (allowance)".

Comment: @Jun Yes, it does, and it is common.

Comment: @Dan,thank you for the follwup. Not sure if it applies to this case yet, but it's certainly a good word to know.

Comment: @Marv, Based on your idea, i feel like "scale factor range" might do.. how does it sound?

Comment: I guess maximum/minimum scaling factor will do.

Comment: Scale[ing] factor range would define the maximum and minimum, it would be the range of scaling factors handled. I wasn't sure if you were seeking a term for the range or the upper boundary of the range, I.e Maximum

Comment: @Marv, it could be either for this case, since "range" indicates maximum and minimum. Sorry it was unclear. Thank you.

Comment: Stick with standard conventions, since many of your readers will not be native speakers. A maximum scaling coefficient of 1.5 is the same as what you are describing. However, it's far easier to cut the technical jargon and instead of "the upper limit of fluctuation allowance in image size which is specified in %" write "images up to 150% of the original size are allowed".

Comment: Could you re-phrase that for clarity, please?
Why did you not use “the upper limit of fluctuation allowance in image size which is specified as/by/through the range of percentage of size fluctuation for sensor to accept to detect the shape (image) which makes 150% to mean that the sensor will detect an upscaled original image in all upscaling rate from 101% to 150%, such as a 102%, 117%, or 142% bigger image to the original image”?
That’s difficult to follow and d’you think it was less, or more difficult your way?

Comment: Further, did you notice that generally, terms expressed as percentages are simply expressed, not defined thus? A "maximum size fluctuation allowance" can be defined however you like but if expressing it as a percentage is part of the definition, what rule are you following, please?

Answer (score 1):

Generally there is an argot associated with items of a technical nsture. You're not the first, I'd suggest, who has come up with an image sensor. A useful port of call is to look at the technical reports that go along with image sensors to see how manufacturers are already referring to such 'fluctuation' ranges ...

Comment: This is the best answer so far. Image sensors come in many forms, and the question doesn’t provide enough context. It sounds like the system is supposed to detect a reference shape in an arbitrary input image, and that the analogous shape in the input image can vary in size. Problems like this have been around for fifty years. The literature around them will have the terminology for sure.

Answer (score 0):

A rather technical term may be **maximum absolute deviation**

> *"The maximum absolute deviation around an arbitrary point is the maximum of the absolute deviations of a sample from **that point**."*[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation#Maximum_absolute_deviation)

In your case, *that  point* should refer to the *true value*. For example, your image sensors is applied on something of size *10*, it measures *15*, then the absolute deviation for that measurement (measurement implies comparing with *true value*) is |15-10|=5.

You also distinguish between upper and lower deviations. You might replace *absolute* by *upper* and *lower* to indicate that. An example of that is done engineering:

> *"Upper deviation: the difference between the maximum possible component size and the basic size."*[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_tolerance#Mechanical_component_tolerance)
>
> *"Lower deviation: the difference between the minimum possible component size and the basic size."*[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_tolerance#Mechanical_component_tolerance)

So you would use ***maximum upper deviation*** and ***maximum lower deviation***.

Of course you could always express this percentually, you could then speak of ***maximum upper percent deviation*** and ***maximum lower percent deviation***, *'percent deviation'* is also use here[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviation_(statistics)#Normalization).